# GnuCash Cashflow Report Account Display Depth

Tags: gnucash, cash-flow

In a GnuCash Cashflow report how can i change the "Account Display Depth" of the sections?

- Money into selected accounts comes from
- Money out of selected accounts goes to

---

Detail:

In GnuCash's CashFlow Report there are four sections to the display:

1. Selected Accounts (at the top)
2. Money into selected accounts comes from
3. Money out of selected accounts goes to
4. Difference (at the bottom)

The option to modify the "Account Display Depth" only impacts the 1st part of the display (the Selected Accounts section).  How can I change the depth of sections 2 and 3?  Am I missing something?

To find the "Account Display Depth" setting go to:
   GnuCash > Reports > Income & Expense > CashFlow report > Options > Accounts

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't modify the display depth of the 'Money into' and 'Money out' sections.  Note however that these sections display the fully expanded Expense and Income accounts - so they are automatically full depth level.  But if you're looking for a summarized cash flow at a specific depth level there, you're out of luck.

The 'Profit & Loss' report might be closer to what you're looking for and allows you to edit the depth for both 'Revenue' and 'Expenses' simultaneously (but not independently).